# Eigen decomposition of two matrix equation

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

I have fallowing eigen equation:

$$ C_{\tau}r_i = C_0r_i\lambda_i $$
where $C_{\tau}r_i$ and $C_0$ are non-positive definitive matrices and $r_i$ and $\lambda_i$ are eigenvectors and eigenvalues. Nevertheless in my software (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/eig) I can only input o one matrix, not two. How should I transform the equation to work with one matrix, is like fallowing, okay ?

$$ C_{\tau}r_i = C_0r_i\lambda_i \rightarrow  C_0^{-1}C_{\tau}r_i = r_i\lambda_i$$
and then I perform eigendecomposition on $C_0^{-1}C_{\tau}$ ?

Comment: Are you sure that $C_0$ is invertible?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, $C_0$ is invertible